# Return length of json array from observable when subscribe function has finished

Tags: angular, subscribe

I have a function that gets the observable with json array in it, as a response from http get:

```
 public getCountofProducts() {

        this.productService.getAllProducts().subscribe
        (
            (products) => {
                if (products!= null) {
                    this.productsLength = products.length;
                }
            }
        );
        return this.productsLength;
    }
```

Usage of function:

```
public getItems()
{
this.items=[

count: this.getCountofProducts()

            ]
}
```

**getAllproducts() response:**
 returns an observable with array of values

Right now, the function is returning '0' as the subscribe function does not finish and I get the initialized value, that is '0'

If I do console.log inside the subscribe function, the correct value is displayed.

What could be the way to get the value, once the subscribed function has finished?

Comment: The issue you're having is that you're treating an **asychronous** piece of code as if it was **synchronous**.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of subscribing to the Observable. You could transform the `Observable` to `Promise` by `.toPromise()`. You would also need to make the function `async` and put `await` before the function you applied `.toPromise()`. Then the products array will be stored in the variable called products and after that you can use it normally.

**Example:**

```
public async getCountofProducts() {
    const products = await this.productService.getAllProducts().toPromise();
    if(products !== null) {
      return products.length;
    } else {
      return 0;
    }
  }
```

When you call this function you have to call it in `async` function with `await` before if you don't call it like this it will return only the ZoneAwarePromise. Instead of this you can also access the value like `Promise` using `.then()`.

```
//You can call it like this
public async someFunction() {
 console.log(await this.getCountofProduts);
}
//OR
public someFunction() {
  this.getCountofProducts().then((result) => {console.log(result)});
}
```

Comment: I tried it: 
I am getting this as the response: 
ZoneAwarePromise {__zone_symbol__state: null, __zone_symbol__value: Array(0)}
__zone_symbol__state: null
__zone_symbol__value: []
__proto__: Object

Comment: @MariumMalik I have tried it with jsonplaceholder and it is working. Could you please add your http.get() request to the question?

Comment: Did you add `await` before the `this.productService.getAllProducts().toPromise();`?

Comment: No! I want await here. So, await at your place seems to be correct

Comment: Ok, I am sorry. I have found the issue and updated the answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189401/discussion-between-josef-katic-and-marium-malik).

Answer (score 0):

Right now I think of two options: The first one to return the server call and subscribing to it in your component or otherwise to return a promise.

**First Option:**

In your component:

```
public getItems()
{
    this.productService.getAllProducts().subscribe((products: Array<any>) => {
        this.items=[
            count: products ? products.length : 0;
        ]
    });

}
```

**Second option:**

*product.service.ts*

```
getAllProducts(): Promise<any[]> {
    return this.http.get('YOUR_URL').toPromise();
}
```

Your call would look like this.

```
public getCountofProducts() {
    return this.productService.getAllProducts().then
    (
        (products) => {
            if (products!= null) {
                this.productsLength = products.length;
                return this.productsLength;
            }
        }
    );
}
```

And in your component:

```
public getItems()
{
    this.getCountofProducts().then((len:number) => {
        this.items=[
            count: len
        ]
    });
 }
```

Comment: In your second section of code, you are returning this.productsLenth and this.productsService.getAllProducts. For me it returns the value of first one only, not the second one (which is basically required)

Answer (score 0):

Try this and please let me know if there are any issues

```
 public getCountofProducts() {
    this.productService.getAllProducts().subscribe
    (
      (products) => {
          if (products!= null) {
             this.getCount(products);
             return this.productsLength;
           }
           else{
             return 0;
           }
       }
     );
 }

 public getCount(products){
    this.productsLength=this.products.length;
 }
```